# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm using CustomTableCell in my project. I can see the "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" is returning a valid cell in the method  "cellForRowAtIndexPath"  as it should eg whenever the table is reloaded.

In the CustomTableCell I have some images that I want to reuse, without downloading them again. However everytime i get a "nil" with the "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" when used inside "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" delegate method.

The original table was not destroyed. The table is class object and I can see it is the same as the tableView received in the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" parameter.

This behavior is consistent with out viewcontrollers in my project where I have used tableview.

I'm using ARC. Any idea what could be wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you trying to dequeue a cell within didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I'm calling other ViewController from "didSelectRowAtIndexPath", and I wanted to pass some data that were fetched in the CustomCell Asynchronously.

Comment: I agree with Till. Your design is flawed.

Comment: Why fetching any data from that view. A view is not really the right place for holding data. That is done within your data model.

Comment: Because I wanted to do some Async http requests specific to a cell. Can't think of another way to do it, unless I wanted to store everything outside of the context of the cell. But again, any idea why dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is not working in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" delegate ? Deque method belongs to the tableview, so it should work nomatter where it is called from as long as the cell reference is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a little vague, but I believe you're simply trying to access your custom cell from within "didSelectRowAtIndexPath". If this is the case, then you should utilize:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableCell *myCell = (CustomTableCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Then you're free to access any part of your custom cell that you wish.

In case your curious:

"dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" is utilized to reduce the amount of object allocations & deallocations by reusing table cells that have "moved" beyond the visible range. i.e If you have a table with 1000 cells, but only 10 are visible at any given time. ~10 cells will be created and reused over and over again. Thus, when called dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will pull one of these cells off the stack of cells that aren't currently being utilized, or create one if the stack is empty.